# Bootstrap Scaffolding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am currently trying to figure out how to get two classes to float side by side while using Bootstrap, What I wish to accomplish is to get my text to float to the left and image float to the right! Here is my code:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
  <div id="test-1" class="span6"></div>
  <div id="test-2" class="span6"></div>
</div>

body {
  background-color: black;
}
#test-1 {
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
#test-2 {
  background-image: url("http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Is you mean that img on right side of the area and text at left side of area ? Then you should use pull-left and pull-right classes of bootstrap

Comment: @sagar Yeah that is right

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you actually using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both `pull-left` & `pull-right` or `col-xs-6`, depending upon what exactly you want to achieve.

Here's the code followed by jsfiddle link showing both things done:

```css
    body {
      background-color: black;
    }
    #test-1 {
      background-color: white;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
    }
    #test-2 {
      background-image: url("http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="row-fluid">
          <div id="test-1" class="span6 pull-left"></div>
          <div id="test-2" class="span6 pull-right"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div id="test-1" class="span6 col-xs-6"></div>
          <div id="test-2" class="span6 col-xs-6"></div>
        </div>
```

Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/jLfcpssz/

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap has a class called [pull-right and pull-left](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats) I think those may work for you

```css
body {
  background-color: black!important;
}
#test-1 {
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
#test-2 {
  background-image: url("http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="test-1" class="col-md-6 span6 pull-left"></div>
    <div id="test-2" class="col-md-6 span6 pull-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```