# What is the proper way to use bootstrap scaffolding on adminbsb cards

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I am currently coding a DJANGO app, where I present a list of adminbsb cards, and would like to present more information on the header of the card. Nevertheless, if I try to float elements into the header, it does not seen to follow the rules, I put this:

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        
 some script here
        

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            Fluid 12
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">
                    Fluid 6
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
                        <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card">

            <div class="bg-green row-fluid inline-group">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                        Fluid 12
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span6">
                                Fluid 6
                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                    <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
                                    <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="body">
                <strong>Nulla at elementum quam, luctus feugiat ipsum</strong><br/>
                <strong><small>Vestibulum suscipit ornare dui consequat sodales. Maecenas eget sollicitudin diam. Aenean
                    in
                    augue arcu. Proin viverra velit eu elit eleifend posuere. Nunc ac arcu erat.</small></strong><br/>
                <!-- <a href="% url 'detalles' tar.numtar %}">{ tar.descorta|truncatechars:300 }}</a> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
    </div>


    </div>
</section>
```

And get this

[image]

As it should give me something like this
[image]

I have no idea what could be missing. The adminbsb and bootstrap libraries are present.

Answer (score 0):

### First time, I have tried Scaffolding. It is similar with bootstrap, no more difference that's why i try to give answer for this.

> **Please check and then let me know. Is it working or not. You want the same or not.**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span9">
    Level 1 column
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span6">Level 2 column
         <div class="row-fluid">
           <div class="span3">Level 3</div>
           <div class="span3">Level 3</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span3">Level 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Below, Code which is inside the card.**

> **Explanation:**
>
> - If you want column size 12 in all the view. Then, there is no need to give all **col-* [(*) - lg, md, sm ,xs]** Grid Class.
>   you can use only col-12. It will take size 12 for all the viewport.
> - Inside the class **"span6"**. you will have to take **"span"** column size is equal to sum of 6.
>   **Like:** Inside the class **"span6"** you can give **"span3"** and **"span3"** which is the sum of **6**. You can take any size of columns, it's up to you. but, it should be equal to the **sum of 6**. **Example:** 6 = 1+5, 2+4, 3+3, 4+2, 5+1.

```
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="bg-green row-fluid inline-group">
        <div class="span12">
             Fluid 12
           <div class="row-fluid">
             <div class="span6">
                Fluid 6
                 <div class="row-fluid">
                      <div class="span3">Fluid 3</div>
                      <div class="span3">Fluid 3</div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it hasn't, it gives the same column of contents. For some reason it is not possible to make the content of a card header a fluid container.

Comment: You can take Ref. from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074944/bootstrap-scaffolding may be it will help you. I have never work on scaffolding.